# EUSART with PIC16F18346

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, microchip, mplabx

I'm trying to set up serial communication between my PC and PIC16F18346 and I wrote this code:

```
#include "xc8_header.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 32000000

void uart_send(char *data);
void uart_char(char dt);

void main(void) {

    TRISC0 = 0;  //sets pin RC0 as an output
    TRISB = 0;   //LED pin
    RC1PPS = 0b10100; //initializes tx function of the pin
    ANSC0 = 0;   //clears analog reg
    ANSC1 = 0;   //clears analog reg
    SYNC = 0;
    BRGH = 0;    //setting up the baud rate generator
    BRG16 = 0;
    SPBRG = 51;
    SPEN = 1;  //enables the serial port
    TXEN = 1;  //enables transmission
    TX9 = 0;
    
    while(1){
        LATB |= (1<<7);
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATB &= ~(1<<7);
        __delay_ms(500);
        uart_send("WORKING bruuuh");
    }
    
    
    return;
}

void uart_send(char *data){
    
    while(*data){
        uart_char(*data++);
    }
    
}
void uart_char(char dt){
    while(!TXIF);
    TX1REG = dt;
    
}
```

Blinking LED on RB7 is just so I know the code is running.
Now, the issue is when I open the serial port on COM5(checked in the device manager) in putty, nothing happens. I can't find the problem.
Edit: Should probably mention that I'm using FT232RL board and the connections are:

```
232   PIC
GND>>>GND
RX >>> TX
```

Comment: What baud rate you are using? Are they same on both ends? Is COM5 the correct port?

Comment: As much as I like PuTTY for other uses, it's not the most convenient tool to debug UART issues. I can recommend [HTerm](https://www.der-hammer.info/pages/terminal.html). It's freeware and you don't need to install it.

Comment: Baud rate is set to 9600 on both

Comment: @VelVel I installed HTerm, but didn't get any errors, it connects all fine but there is no data received.

Comment: Have you checked the other COM ports, just to make sure?

Comment: Try adding: TRISC1 = 0;

Comment: @VelVel the only other COM port available is COM3 and that one is there all the time. I did check it just in case and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead I added it, and nothing really happened. The RX LED on my FT232RL doesn't blink at all except for 2-3 seconds after I reset the chip and then it writes what looks like line breaks in the port.

Comment: Might try sending individual characters and testing the transmit buffer between each to make sure you are not overrunning the buffer.  Not sure what your "uart_send" function does but if it uses interrupts you might be overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have not connected the correct pin from your PIC to your FT232RL serial adapter.

If there is a problem with your code it's likely in the part you did not post.

This code works in the MPLABX simulator:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 *
 * Created on November 1, 2022, 9:57 AM
 */

// PIC16F18346 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with 2x PLL (32MHz))
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR; Weak pull-up enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT disabled; SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly (subject to the unlock sequence))
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR. MCLRE configuration bit is ignored.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _XTAL_FREQ 32000000ul

#include <xc.h>

void UART_Init(void)
{
    RXPPS  = 0b10000;                       /* Assign RC0 to UART RX */
    RC1PPS = 0b10100;                       /* Assign UART TX to RC1 */

    TRISC1 = 0;                             // sets UART TX pin RC1 as an output
    LATC1  = 1;                             /* Set UART TX ouput high */
    ANSC0 = 0;                              // clears analog reg
    ANSC1 = 0;                              // clears analog reg
    SYNC = 0;
    BRGH = 0;                               // setting up the baud rate generator
    BRG16 = 0;
    SPBRG = (_XTAL_FREQ/(9600ul*64ul))-1ul; /* See EXAMPLE 31-1 DS40001839E-page 374 */
    SPEN = 1;                               // enables the serial port
    TXEN = 1;                               // enables transmission
    TX9 = 0;
}
void uart_char(char dt){
    while(!TXIF);
    TX1REG = dt;
    
}
void uart_send(char *data){
    
    while(*data){
        uart_char(*data++);
    }
    
}
void main(void) 
{
    UART_Init();
    __delay_ms(50);             /* Let UART TX output pin be at stop bit state for 50 milliseconds before sending characters after a reset. */
    TRISB = 0;   //LED pin
    uart_send("\r\nPIC16F18346 UART example start built on " __DATE__ " at "  __TIME__ "\r\n");
    for(;;)
    {
        LATB |= (1<<7);
        __delay_ms(500);
        LATB &= ~(1<<7);
        __delay_ms(500);
        uart_send("WORKING bruuuh\r\n");
    }
}
```